# Harbor replication rule limit to 10 latest images

Tags: docker, harbor

I am using harbor as a local registry, I created a replication rule that copies my ECR registry but I have hundreds of images and I only want to replicate the latest 10, I can have a retention rule but then it will pull the images again every time.

how can I do this?